# Converting DataBox from SlimDX to SharpDX (dBox.Data.Write)

Tags: pointers, sharpdx, data-stream

I am trying to figure out how to convert the code below (which is for SlimDX) over to SharpDX.

```
var texure2d = new Texture2D(_device, texDesc);
var dbox = _deviceContext.MapSubresource(texure2d, 0, MapMode.WriteDiscard, MapFlags.None);
foreach (var thisColor4 in color) // color is a List<Color4>
{
    dbox.Data.Write((byte)(thisColor4.Red * 255));
    dbox.Data.Write((byte)(thisColor4.Green * 255));
    dbox.Data.Write((byte)(thisColor4.Blue * 255));
    dbox.Data.Write((byte)(0));
}
_deviceContext.UnmapSubresource(texure2d, 0);
```

I also have a similar questions with DataRectagle:

```
var heightMapTexure = new Texture2D(device, textureDesc,
    new DataRectangle(
        HeightMapWidth * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Half)), // Pitch
        new DataStream(hmap.ToArray(), false, false) // dataStream
    )
);
```

Reading through the SlimDX source it looks like they store a `DataStreams` while SharpDX stores a `pointer` and I am unsure how to proceed as I have never worked with pointers before.  Any help with how to get this working or an alternative method to achieve the same results would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I have figured this out on my own, the way I was able to do this is:

```
DataStream mappedResource;
deviceContext.MapSubresource(texure2d, 0, MapMode.WriteDiscard, MapFlags.None, out mappedResource);
foreach (var thisColor4 in color)
{
    mappedResource.Write((byte)(thisColor4.Red * 255));
    mappedResource.Write((byte)(thisColor4.Green * 255));
    mappedResource.Write((byte)(thisColor4.Blue * 255));
    mappedResource.Write((byte)(0));
}
deviceContext.UnmapSubresource(texure2d, 0);
```

---

```
var heightMapTexure = new Texture2D(device, textureDesc,
    new DataRectangle(
        DataStream.Create(hmap.ToArray(), false, false).DataPointer,
        HeightMapWidth * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(Half))   
    )
);
```

Hope this helps other that may have a similar question.

Comment: Don't forget to dispose the DataStream after you're done with it.